# ATS working for iOS10, but not iOS9?

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, ios10, app-transport-security

We recently changed `SSL` certificate to match the guidelines from Apple for ATS.

I had previously had the `NSAllowsArbritaryLoads` key set to true before our server was ATS compatible, to allow traffic.

Turning this to false, my phone on iOS10 now works to consume services from this server, however phones still on iOS9 are failing due to the SSL exception

> iOS device was suffering from prior to the SSL certificate update
>   (NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)).

Obviously I can set the key back to true, however then it seems I will have problems getting the app reviewed.

Is there something else I should be doing to cater for these iOS9 devices?

Many thanks,
    Spordan

Comment: If you hit the server in Safari, does it complain about the server certifiate?

Comment: Are you using a domain name or IP address to connect to your server?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see your original comment! Yes, we're using an IP address to connect to the server, and no complaints from Safari

Comment: Starting with iOS 10, ATS is not enforced on IP addresses.  That is why it is working in iOS 10 and not iOS9.  So something is still not right with your https implementation.  If you are running OS X 10.11 or later, run the following command `nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your IP address.

Comment: Also, this is a good resource to troubleshooting ATS issues: http://timekl.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/